# How to search wikicode? (source wikicode, not rendered HTML)

Tags: mediawiki

I am looking for the string `lat=13.7436853` in [Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org).

**PROBLEM:** The string is in the wikicode, not in the visible resulting HTML.
Google does not help: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:en.wikivoyage.org+13.7436853

How to search for wikicode of Wikivoyage?
Preferably without downloading a [dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikivoyage/).

*(by the way, that string is actually in the wikicode of the [Rattanakosin](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Rattanakosin) article)*

Comment: And you found out that that string is in the wikicode of that article by downloading a dump?

Comment: @w3d Yes, but it could also be found simply by visiting https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/index.php?title=Bangkok/Rattanakosin&action=edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Wikivoyage search finds that page just fine:

https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=default&search=lat%3D13.7436853&fulltext=Search